# Do most (or all) USB (wireless and corded) barcode scanners submit <Carriage Return><Line Feed>?

Tags: java, barcode, barcode-scanner

I am currently working on a retail (point of sale) application. I have a feeling that I don't really need to hard code anything for my software to be compatible with a barcode scanner. From what I have read online, there are a lot of barcode scanners that submit <Carriage Return><Line Feed>, which is the same as the user pressing the 'Enter' key. With this in mind, I can easily code my application to place item information in a table upon the user pressing the 'Enter' key.

What I need to know is this...

Are there barcode scanners that do NOT use <Carriage Return><Line Feed> functionality? If so, is it possible for a user with very little knowledge in technology to set the barcode scanner to use this functionality?

Also, how would a user know what a barcode scanner submits to their computer (Ex: whether the barcode scanner submits <Tab> or <Carriage Return>), prior to purchasing a barcode scanner?

Comment: That sort of thing is invariably a configurable option in any decent barcode scanner, and there is no firm answer.

Comment: So, do all (or most) barcode scanners allow this function to be configured?

Comment: It depends very much on the model, but generally you can scan special codes to configure the scanner as in [this manual](http://www.idautomation.com/barcode-scanners/programming-manuals/SC7-USB-2D-Barcode-Scanner-Manual.pdf). You'll want to favor Super User for general computing questions, though.

Comment: CupawnTae, thank you for the edit. I couldn't figure out how to get it to display like that. (Haha...)

Comment: I think it's safe to say that the ones you encounter that do not submit a CRLF are the ones that allow it to be configured.

Comment: I don't know about all/most. There's probably a few million brands/modes out there. I've encountered exactly TWO in my career,  and both allowed total control over pre/post character insertion. Take from that what you will.

Comment: Okay, awesome. Now, let's say that someone using my software application is researching barcode scanners, so that they can decide which one to purchase. Is this functionality something that you can typically see, prior to purchasing the barcode scanner? In other words, if I tell someone in a section of my software... "Please ensure that the barcode scanner that you purchase supports <Carriage Return><Line Feed> functionality.", is this something that they'd be able to determine while shopping?

Comment: I talked to Zebra Tech Support. (Hilarious that I didn't consider it earlier.)  It looks like they have a direct programming utility called 123Scan.  According the Tech Support Rep, it can accomplish what I need.  I'll report back here once I've been able to use it.  Here's a link, in case anyone is curious: https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/software/utilities/123scan-utility.html